# Why would components in this Blazor app fail to render?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm writing a Blazor app and obviously I want to get some components rendered in there. I've just tried adding a basic navigation element to my main layout but it's not rendering. I can see the element on the DOM, but that element is empty.

I went with some fairly simple content to start with in my NavMenu component that I'm trying to include on MainLayout.cshtml:

```
<h1>WHYYYY????</h1>
```

I've also taken a pretty simple layout on my MainLayout.cshtml page:

```
@inherits BlazorLayoutComponent


<NavMenu />

<div class="body-content">
    @Body
</div>
```

The file structure in my project seems uncomplicated:

[image]

So I'm at a loss here as to what I've overlooked. It looks like Blazor *knows* there's something it should be rendering to the page - that's why I can see the NavMenu element in the DOM. But there's never any content rendered inside that element. What's missing?

[image: NavMenu Blazor component]

I'm running the latest (at time of writing) version of Blazor: 0.5.1.

Comment: I should add: I've also tried adding the `<NavMenu />` component in other pages (e.g. /Pages/Index.cshtml) with the same results.

Comment: Could you also share the code of NavMenu?

Comment: Ok. I get it. NavMenu only contains the <h1>?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this, but with everything I could think of it remains working on my side. Could you share your complete project somewhere?

Comment: But first, check my answer below, that must be it.

Comment: @Flores Yep - I've kept it _really_ basic for now just for testing purposes, so the NavMenu code literally has one line containing the `<h1 />` element until I can figure out why nothing's showing up at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the root cause was related to namespaces and casing.

When I originally set up the project, I created it using the command line in VS Code. Out of habit, I wrote everything in lowercase (i.e. `dotnet new blazor -o myapp`).

As a personal preference, I like my namespaces to be title cased, so some time later I decided to "tidy up" and change `myapp` to `Myapp`. I went through the code to refactor to the new titlecase name and everything compiled, so I carried on working... until a few weeks later when I went back to do some work on a component and noticed it wasn't behaving.

It turns out that razor pages are automatically namespaced based on folders and a subset of those are included in the *_ViewImports.cshtml* page. That file still referenced the lower case namespace and pages looking for a lowercase project root were no longer able to find the right shared components.

So unsurprisingly, it's an entirely self-inflicted issue and yes I feel very silly for not thinking it through properly from the start.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably running into a bug with the .csproj file. It should look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
   <RunCommand>dotnet</RunCommand>
   <RunArguments>blazor serve</RunArguments>
   <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser" Version="0.5.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="0.5.1" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli" Version="0.5.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Yours has most likely extra stuff in it, that prevents the component from compiling. This typically happens when adding files or copying them. See: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1206

Comment: Great suggestion! I'll re-check that tonight because I'm sure you're on the right track - I had made a couple of additions to the items in the ItemGroup section.

Comment: Nope. I've done some clean-up and with the exception of a project reference, the proj file looks essentially as you've described here. Looks like the Github issue you referenced is still pretty active and it's a known issue - just with different underlying symptoms than I'm seeing.

Comment: That makes me very curious.. could you share the code somewhere?

Comment: Not easily. Happy to move this conversation to chat to discuss though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Remove="documents\InvoiceTemplate.razor" />
<Content Remove="Pages\ComponentInvoice.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Thank you @Flores.  This was in my csproj file - I only have this happen in projects where I'm using ABCPDF - and I've seen other threads where ABCPDF is the suspect in situations like this.